# Trouble in understanding control flow in python class (in a google app engine)

Tags: python, class, control-flow

Guys, I'm having some trouble in understanding control flow in python class, i.e., what is happing with the code step by step. Given the short code bellow, I'd like to know: when the class MainPage is called it just  executes every thing that is inside that  class? In linear order? (the first line, after  the second etc.)

[image]

Comment: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a Python file is executed, every statement in the file is executed from the top to the bottom.  In your case, there are six statements:

```
from ..
from ..
class MainPage ..
application = ..
def main() ..
if __name__ ..
```

The first two find other Python modules, and execute all of their statements, which likely just define a bunch of classes, and then define some names in your module using values from those other modules.  So after the first two statements, we have `webapp` and `run_wsgi_app` defined.

The third statement defines the class `MainPage`.  It does this by executing the statements inside the class body, in this case there is only one: a `def`.  Note that executing a `def` statement doesn't execute the statements in the function body, it just collects those statements into a named function.  When the class body ends, all the names defined become attributes of the class.

The fourth statement calls `webapp.WSGIApplication`, and assigns the result to `application`.

The fifth statement defines a function called `main`.

The sixth statement looks at the name `__name__`.  Every time a Python file is executed, it is given a `__name__` variable.  If the file is the main one being run, that is, the one Python started with, the value of `__name__` is `"__main__"`.  This if statement is an idiom meaning, "Am I the main program?"  In this case, it is, so the body of the if statement is also executed.

The body of the if simply calls the `main()` function, which itself invokes the `run_wsgi_app` function, passing your already-built `application` value to it.

Running a WSGI app is involved, but basically amounts to, "wait until someone visits a URL, and then map the URL to some code, and then execute the code."  In your case, you provided a URL map that associated "/" with `MainPage`.  Once someone visits the / URL, a `MainPage` object will be created, and a method on it will be invoked.

In particular, because the HTTP method used to visit / was GET, the WSGI app runner calls the `.get()` method on the `MainPage` object.  The statements in the `get` method are executed in sequence, writing some data to the response.  When there are no more statements in the function body, it returns.  The WSGI application container sends that response back to the web browser!

This program never ends, because the WSGI application runner loops forever waiting for the next URL visit.  But if it didn't, once the last statement in your main file completed, the Python program would be done, and the process would end.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and excellent answer, Ned. It clarified to me several others aspects. But I still have a doubt concerning this: "Once someone visits the / URL, a MainPage object will be created, and a method on it will be invoked". When the MainPage object is created, it will always executed the procedures inside that object (like get, post etc.)?

Comment: The only way the app can find code to run is by looking on an object for a method.  So yes, it always runs a method on that object.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't execute linearly.

First, you define a class that will prepare data for a page when a certain method (`get`) is called. This is the class definition of `MainPage`.

Then, you register this class with the system, also telling it when to use this class. You can see that happening on the code that starts with `application = ...`. The code there tells the webapp framework to use `MainPage` when the URL path is `/`. As you can imagine, you can register multiple classes for different routes here. Notice that this piece of code is executed once before `main` is called.

Then, you define the program entry point: `main()`. It is a simple one: you tell the framework  to start running with the `application` you constructed. The code under `run_wsgi_app` waits for a request, checks the URL path against registered classes when it receives one, obtains a response from the registered class by calling its `get()` method, and sends a response. Of course, this is a gross oversimplification of what's really happening in there.

Finally, you call main in the last code block.

To summarize: we first call `main`, which calls `run_wsgi_app`, which instantiates a `MainPage` and calls its `get()` method using the structure `application`.

Comment: Thanks, vhallac your explanation is simple and clear. But, I'd like to know: why when main() is called and object is created (MainPage is istantiated) it executes the get method WHEN there is nothing calling get, but only a definition of get (def get(self)). I'm not understanding how the control flow happens here, because if it was a ordinary function script, after defining a procedure I would have to call it. Could you give me an explanation about this?

Comment: The WSGI app runner calls .get() because the HTTP method GET was used to visit the site.

Comment: Thanks more one time, Ned. I'm begining to understand what happens, though "because the HTTP method GET was used to visit the site" still sound a little obscure to me. But know I think that, with more exemples I'll be able to understand (with other exemples beyond get(), like post()). I think get procedure has this a litte occult called, but others procedures (like post()) will have a more clear function call. Thanks for sharing your knowledge and your time.

Comment: @Pythonista'sApprentice The calling of `get` is a promise from the `webapp` framework: when a request is received, and a path in the `application` (or whatever name you use) matches the path, the class from the matching path is obtained, an instance is created, and `get` method is called. This all happens inside `run_wsgi_app()` function.